# View active Infopath Form Services sessions?

Tags: 2013, infopath, monitoring

Is there a way to view if anyone is currently using InfoPath Forms Services (IPFS)?

I'm concerned that if I deploy a Site Collection Feature - which will recycle the app pool - it will play havoc with IPFS. Better that I can confirm no-one is using a form, and then proceed with feature deployment. (In this case, I can't really wait until after-hours etc).

Comment: None that I am aware of.  If you can't wait till after hours than what does it matter?  Active queries will fail, but otherwise just filling out a form will be available as long as it is loaded before your recycle and they save after it is back online.

Answer (score 0):

Infopath services use State Services( for session management), i don't know if you can get the information from state services or not?

Couple of ways you can deploy the solution without affecting the user.

as Jesus mentioned deploy the solution after hours and ask for downtime and also recycle will not affect the filling the form rather if user submitting the form then recycle App Pool cause the issue. But I am sure only user has to re submit the form.

you know App Pool recycled once in 24 hours( usually between midnight to 3 AM). you can schedule your deployment near to that time frame. You can check the timing from IIS.

Comment: Well it's good to know a recycle won't affect form-filling. Is there any documentation on that?